# How i get the real value in select form zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to get the real value, instead of the number position of a `Select` form field
I explain it with one example:

first in the form

```
$procesa=new Querys();  
$datosAsignaturas=$procesa->getDatosAsignaturas();
$groups = array();
foreach ($datosAsignaturas as $id => $list) {
    $groups[$id] =$list["nombreA"];
}
$selection= $factory-> createElement(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
    'name' => 'subjects',
    'attributes' =>  array(
        'id' => 'subjects',                
        'options' => $groups
    ), 
)); 

$this->add($selection);
```

Second, the view

```
<div class="form_element">
        <?php $element = $form->get('subjects');
         ?>
        <label>
            <?php echo $element->getOption('value'); ?>
        </label>
        <?php echo $this->formSelect($element); ?>
    </div>
```

third
["subjects"]=> string(1) "1"

i need something like this
["subjects"]=> string(1) "Maths"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean :

```
<div class="form_element">
    <?php $element = $form->get('subjects');
     ?>
    <label>
        <?php echo $element->getOption('label'); //-------- label instead value?>
    </label>
    <?php echo $this->formSelect($element); ?>
</div>
```

And about the form

```
$procesa=new Querys();  
$datosAsignaturas=$procesa->getDatosAsignaturas();
$groups = array();
foreach ($datosAsignaturas as $id => $list) {
    $groups[$id] =$list["nombreA"];
}
$selection= $factory-> createElement(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
    'name' => 'subjects',
    'attributes' =>  array(
        'id' => 'subjects',                
        'options' => $groups
    ), 
    'options'=>array(
       'label'=>"Your label",
       'description' => 'your description',
       'value_options' => array(
         '0' => 'French',
         '1' => 'English',
         '2' => 'Japanese',
         '3' => 'Chinese',
       ),
     )
)); 

$this->add($selection);
```

Comment: you forgot to add **'options'=>array(
       'label'=>"Your label",
       'description' => 'your description'
     )** in the form class. Also as Sam said some **value_options** and add **<?php echo $element->getOption('label');** in the view script

Comment: *Real value* means the key or the value of your options array (for you) ?

Comment: the real value is Chinese not 3

Comment: So Sam told you the right answer ! **foreach($elemLanguage->getValueOptions() as $id => $language) {
    echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$id} - {$language}</option>\n";
}**

Answer (score 1):

Proper assignement of values to a [`Zend\Form\Element\Select`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.elements.html#select) is through the means of `value_options` inside `options` or using the element function `setValueOptions()`. Here a simple example:

```
$form->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'name' => 'language',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Which is your mother tongue?',
        'empty_option' => 'Please choose your language',
        'value_options' => array(
            '0' => 'French',
            '1' => 'English',
            '2' => 'Japanese',
            '3' => 'Chinese',
        ),
    )
));
```

Now if you need to access the value options like this, you simply call `getValueOptions()` on the element and you'll receive exactly the same array as above. Then you could do something like this (which I'm assuming is what you're trying to do):

```
$elemLanguage = $form->get('language');

echo "<select name='{$elemLanguage->getName()}'>\n";
foreach($elemLanguage->getValueOptions() as $id => $language) {
    echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$id} - {$language}</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
```